# Did Colgate face marketing issues in Argentina because its name meant 'go hang yourself'?

Tags: consumer-products, marketing

Over the years, I've heard the following anecdote repeated often as an example of marketing-gone-bad:

> In Argentina (or sometimes, Latin America), Colgate-Palmolive faced huge hurdles in marketing their brand of toothpaste, [Colgate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colgate_%28toothpaste%29), as it effectively translate to, *Go Hang Yourself!*

Is this true? [Here is one](http://www.omg-facts.com/Business/Colgate-Had-Troubles-Marketing-In-Spanis/749) of many sites that make this claim.

Comment: Related: http://translate.google.com/#es/en/cuelgate

Comment: Also: http://msgboard.snopes.com/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=95;t=000458;p=1

Answer (score 11):

I can vouch for the translation: "colgate" here means ["hang yourself"](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=colgarse) or "hang you". Notice that this differs from "normal" Spanish (Spain and most Latin America), because our "[voseo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo)" (for familiar second person speaking) alters grammar -in Spain it would be "cuélgate".

This matches the testimony [here](http://msgboard.snopes.com/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=95;t=000458;p=1).

It must have been surely an unfortunate coincidence for the marketers, but I don't believe that it was a great deal; people just understand and get over it. And I don't think that the coincidence is so terrible as it might sound. First, we don't normally use that word to as a colloquial insult or curse, as in English - Spanish speakers might say instead: '*matate*' (kill yourself) o '*pegate un tiro*' (fire yourself). Furthermore, the verb "colgar" has quite other meanings, apart from the act of killing hanging from a rope. For example, currently, it's also used as younger slang for "to take part of something" (similar to "hang out") and there are more related "positive" meanings.

There has been some much more unfortunate coincidences: the [Mitsubishi Pajero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Pajero) had to be changed (to [Montero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Montero)) because *pajero* is a [very strong and vulgar word](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=pajero) in many Spanish-speaking regions (*wanker*).

Update: an interesting point is raised in the comments, regarding the pronunciation. We (I'm speaking about Argentina, and most non-English-speaking countries) are used to pronounce most "foreign" words not by following the Spanish phonetic rules, but with the original sounds (well... approximately). Say, we pronounce "Seven Up" as if the last syllable had a Spanish 'a'. But a word like 'Colgate' can make us hesitate, because it feels like a Spanish word, but we (might) know that it's foreign. And, indeed, a few people here pronounce 'colgueit', ala English. A consensus is normally formed, often driven by TV-radio announcements. Hence (and this is the point of this disgression) one might guess that the marketing should have try to impose the 'foreign' pronounciation in the announcements, to dispell the unfortunate coincidence with the Spanish verb. However, for some reason, that didn't happen (because the Spanish pronounciation was already established, or because the coincidence didn't matter? I'd bet for the later, but that's just my guess). See for example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVsqw4snjag) (Mexico, ~1960) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8_GjPXW7sE) (Argentina, ~2010). The same happens in [Italy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2EW1jYhaXs).

Comment: Usually, we'd ask for references, but this matches the testimony [here](http://msgboard.snopes.com/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=95;t=000458;p=1), and I don't think there's any reason to doubt your description, especially given that Colgate did not change their brand name.

Comment: Thank you. While the answer is helpful, it doesn't really confirm if _Colgate_ faced any marketing issues due to this in Argentina or other Latin American countries.

Comment: Please avoid giving unreferenced answers. I've added them for you - it only takes a minute.

Comment: @vartec - Technically "no va" does translate as "doesn't go", but "no va" is pronounced differently than "nova" in Spanish, and "va" probably wouldn't be used in that context and GM never changed the name.  It's basically a witticism along the lines of Found On Road Dead or Fix It Again Tony.

Comment: Would you pronounce the brand name exactly as the verb or do you stress different vowels?

Comment: @nico, Pronounced exactly the same. Some brands do retain English pronunciation, like 'Starbucks', but is not the case for Colgate.

Comment: @nico That's an interesting point (see the updated answer). Remember though that, once we decide to pronounce it as it were a Spanish word, then we have no ambiguity, the pronounciation (stress included) is automatically determined by the spelling.

Comment: @leonbloy: so, which vowel do you stress? The o or the a? In Italian we pronounce Colgate stressing the a, for instance.

Comment: @nico We stress the 'a'